Dscl authenticate OpenLDAP user for MacOS network account
I want to use an OpenLDAP server to authenticate Network Users for MacOS.
My database entry looks like this:
# jdoe, Users, example.com
dn: uid=jdoe,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: posixAccount
cn: John Doe
sn: Doe givenName: John
displayName: John Doe
uid: jdoe
uidNumber: 1001
gidNumber: 5000
homeDirectory: /home/jdoe
loginShell: /bin/bash
mail: jdoe@example.com

I verified that the authentication works by running the command:
ldapwhoami -x -H ldap://192.168.64.3 -D "uid=jdoe,ou=Users,dc=example,dc=com" -W
Where 192.168.64.3 is the address of the server (running in a Ubuntu VM)
In my MacOS client I can reach the server and find the user with
id jdoe

->
uid=1001(jdoe) gid=5000 groups=5000,12(everyone),62(netaccounts),701(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1)

but if I try to authenticate the user through DSCL it doesn't work
dscl /LDAPv3/192.168.64.3 -authonly jdoe

->
Authentication for node /LDAPv3/192.168.64.3 failed. (-14090, eDSAuthFailed)
<dscl_cmd> DS Error: -14090 (eDSAuthFailed)

Maybe for DSCL to work there needs to be additional schemas or configs that are required or am I missing something important?
